# Git detached head - return to earlier commit and apply changes from there

Tags: git

I've made a mess of my git repo and am hoping that there is a fix for this. I tried to do some upgrades of a library dependency that went bad. I couldn't find a way to undo them, so I just decided to go back to an earlier commit and then work from there, thinking that I would merge things later on. However, I wound up with origin/master being detached from the head and now I am unable to push anything to the remote repo. Here is a screen shot of the current state of things:

[image]

I couldn't care less about that branch. I just want it to go back into the hole it crawled out of. But I can't make it happen.

I've tried to revert the commit like this:

`git revert 7921869`

> error: revert is not possible because you have unmerged files.
>   hint: Fix them up in the work tree, and then use 'git add/rm
>   '
>  hint: as appropriate to mark resolution and make a
>   commit.
>  fatal: revert failed

I've also tried to push the changes:

`git push origin HEAD:master`

> To https://xxx@bitbucket.org/xxx/xxx.git  ! [rejected]        HEAD ->
>   master (non-fast-forward)
>  error: failed to push some refs to
>   'https://xxx@bitbucket.org/xxx/xxx.git'
>  hint: Updates were
>   rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote
>  hint:
>   counterpart. Check out this branch and integrate the remote
>   changes
>  hint: (e.g. 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
>   hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for
>   details.

`git push origin master --force`

> error: src refspec master does not match any.
> error: failed to push
>   some refs to
>   'https://xxx@bitbucket.org/xxx/xxx.git'

And I did this:

`git show-ref`

> 79218694bc34715b3d632dc0057f01fc2df2c842 refs/remotes/origin/master

Can anyone help me unwind this so that I don't have a detached head? I need `origin/master` to be consistent with the ddf4a1f commit as if f0dd017 an 7921869 had never happened. If I just do `git checkout master` or `git checkout e416f24` I lose the 4 subsequent commits and I can't let that happen.

Thanks.

**EDIT**

In case I didn't explain this well, the line on the left is perfect. I just need to get the master to point to that final commit such that I can push to the remote again. Forget the pink branch. That is garbage and I don't want to use it at all.

**EDIT 2**

I've followed the advice below by Tim Biegeleisen and I think I'm almost there. Now I have this state:

[image]

So now when I do `git push origin master` I get this:

> To https://xxx@bitbucket.org/xxx/xxx.git
>  
>   ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
> error: failed
>   to push some refs to
>   'https://xxx@bitbucket.org/xxx/xxx.git'
>   hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is
>   behind 
> hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes
>   (e.g. 
> hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again. 
> hint: See the 'Note
>   about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

But if I do as the message says and do `git pull ...` won't I defeat the entire purpose of this and bring back in the garbage from `origin/master`?

Can I just do `git push origin master --force`?

Comment: > you have unmerged files.

this means you did a merge, but were half done. you might need to run `git merge --abort`

Comment: `git push origin master --force` will throw away the two commits that `origin/master` is ahead of the branching point, and push the four commits that `master` is ahead of the branching point to origin. This sounds precisely like the thing you want to achieve.

Comment: It is. And it worked. I'm all fixed up now. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach to end this madness would be to commit any work you have in this detached head state, create a new bona-fide branch, and then cherry-pick the commits you want into `master`.  Here is how you can do this:

```
git commit -m 'final commit detached HEAD'  # save any remaining work
git checkout -b master_detached             # create new branch (perhaps optional)

git checkout master                         # switch to master
git cherry-pick <SHA-1 detached #1>         # cherry-pick 1st commit
git cherry-pick <SHA-1 detached #2>         # cherry-pick 2nd commit
...
```

The command `git cherry-pick <SHA-1>` tells Git to apply a single commit whose hash is `SHA-1` to the current branch, which in this case would be `master`.  In other words, using cherry-pick you can effectively graft the commits you made while in the detached HEAD state onto your `master` branch for safe-keeping.  A cherry-pick can be thought of as a merge of one commit, and as such, you might vet merge conflicts from each cherry-pick operation.

**Update:**

It appears that you made a couple of bad commits on top of your `master` branch in addition to the four commits you made in the detached state.  In this case, you can nuke those two commits from `master`.  So right after the `git checkout master` step above you can try the following:

```
git reset --hard HEAD~2
```

This will roll `master` back from the `7921869` commit to the `e416f24` commit.  After this, simple continue as above by cherry-picking the detached commits.

Since you rewrote the history of the `master` branch, you will now have to push it to the remote via:

```
git push --force origin master
```

Keep in mind that this may not be desirable if `master` is shared by many people.

Comment: Thanks, but I this will carry on the life of the 'master' branch. I don't want those two commits because they screwed everything up. Can I just do `git checkout e416f24` and then cherry pick the commits as you suggest? Will that accomplish the same thing?

Comment: Hmmm...either I misread your question or you don't follow my answer.  I am saying the same thing you are.  Just checkout `master` and then cherry-pick.  The commits you made in the detached HEAD state are _not_ in the `master` branch.

Comment: Probably the latter. When I do `git checkout master` I go to the 7921869 commit. I do NOT want to be there. The commit that I want start applying from is e416f24. I want to throw away f0dd017 and 7921869.

Comment: I'll update my answer to take this information into account.

Comment: Thank you very very much for this. Makes perfect sense. I did this and now have the local `master` in the right place. But I'm still have a problem pushing back to the remote. Would you mind taking a look at my edit #2? Thanks again. I really appreciate it!

Comment: I got it. The final step was simply `git push origin master --force` followed by `git pull origin master`. Thanks so much for your help. Despite my mistakes, I'm getting better with git little by little.